# Variable with decimal gets converted into 2 figures when used in an R1C1 formula

Tags: vba, excel

So my question is very simple. In my VBA code I am retrieving 3 values from 3 cells. 
In the example below, Value1 = 110,5;Value2=100;Value3=120

```
        Value1 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 5).Value
        Value2 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 14).Value
        Value3 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 23).Value
        Cells(k, 4).Formula = "=MIN(" & Value1 & "," & Value2 & "," & Value3 & ")"
```

For an unknown reason the result being displayed within Excel is the following one :

```
=MIN(110;50;100;130), instead of MIN(110,5;100;130)
```

The problem is coming from the fact that the first variable gets converted into 2 variables (110,5 converted into 110;5)

Do you have any solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the list separator in your excel installation - comma or semicolon?

Comment: Is `,` the decimal separator in your locale?

Answer (score 3):

Your comma-as-decimal-placeholder is conflicting with the default EN-US list separator. Use .FormulaLocal and write the formula as it would appear to you on the worksheet.

```
dim value1 as string, value2 as string, value3 as string
Value1 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 5).text
Value2 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 14).text
Value3 = Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 23).text
Cells(k, 4).FormulaLocal = "=MIN(" & Value1 & ";" & Value2 & ";" & Value3 & ")"
'alternate with qualified cell addresses
Cells(k, 4).formula = "=min(" & Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 5).address(external:=true) & "," & _
                                Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 14).address(external:=true) & "," & _
                                Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 23).address(external:=true) & ")"
```

Looking at the way you're using *k*, it could easily be inferred that you are running a loop like `for k=2 to lastRow`. If that is the case, then write all of the formulas at once.

```
with range(Cells(2, 4), cells(lastRow, 4))
    .formula = "=min(" & Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(2, 5).address(0, 1, external:=true) & "," & _
                                Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(2, 14).address(0, 1, external:=true) & "," & _
                                Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(2, 23).address(0, 1, external:=true) & ")"
end with
```

If you are hard-coding values into the worksheet formula, you might as well just write the result value in.

```
Cells(k, 4) = application.min(Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 5).value2, _
                              Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 14).value2, _
                              Worksheets(Countryname).Cells(k, 23).value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA can be us-centric.  Especially since your formula is in quotes, you should be using your system list separator which seems to be `;` and not a `,`

For an internationally aware version try:

```
sep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
Cells(k, 4).FormulaLocal = "=MIN(" & Value1 & sep & Value2 & sep & Value3 & ")"
```